# Are these selectors part of CSS 2.1 or CSS 3?

Tags: css, css-selectors, w3c

Are these selectors part of CSS 2.1, CSS 3, or both?

```
E[att^="val"]
E[att$="val"]
E[att*="val"]
E:last-child
E ~ F
```

---

Are these all the available selectors in CSS?
Please tell me which selector is part of which CSS version?

```
*
E
.class
#id
E F
E > F
E + F
E[attribute]
E[attribute=value]
E[attribute~=value]
E[attribute|=value]
:first-child
:lang()
:before
::before
:after
::after
:first-letter
::first-letter
:first-line
::first-line
E[attribute^=value]
E[attribute$=value]
E[attribute*=value]
E ~ F
:root
:last-child
:only-child
:nth-child()
:nth-last-child()
:first-of-type
:last-of-type
:only-of-type
:nth-of-type()
:nth-last-of-type()
:empty
:not()
:target
:enabled
:disabled
:checked
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All CSS 3.

- [CSS 3 selectors](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/)
- [CSS 2.1 selectors](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#pattern-matching)

The last one `E ~ F` is the [general sibling combinator](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#general-sibling-combinators).

See the [quirksmode.org compatibility table](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/contents.html) for info on which selector is supported by which browser.

Comment: but some are also supported even in IE7

Comment: So to sum this up: `E:last-child`, `E[att^="val"]`, `E[att$="val"]`, `E[att*="val"]`, and `E ~ F` are all to be introduced with CSS 3.

Comment: @Pekka: Sorry, I am wrong, only `E:first-child` was introduced with CSS 2, but not `E:last-child`. So all are to be introduced with CSS 3.

Comment: @Gumbo ah, that's the way I initially read it but I thought `last-child` was part of the package without mentioning. Reverting, cheers.

Comment: @Pekka - sorry ,I updated question. Please give answer to second question also. Thanks.

Comment: @metal-gear Re your edit: I posted two links featuring the complete lists of selectors in CSS 2 and 3. Please go and look them up yourself. When you do, be sure to add the result as an answer here, it's likely to benefit others in the future.

Comment: that list has only CSS 2.1 and CSS 3 selectors. is that mean no selectors were proposed in CSS 1 ans 2?

Comment: @metal CSS1 specification: http://www.w3.org/TR/2008/REC-CSS1-20080411/ (no nice selector table though)

Comment: @Pekka - I think `Class`, `ID` and Contextual selectors were part of CSS 1

Comment: @Pekka - some info on this link also but not much clear http://mobiforge.com/designing/story/comparison-css-21-css-mp-wcss-and-css-level-1

Comment: CSS 1 cheat sheet http://www.digilife.be/quickreferences/QRC/Cascading%20Style%20Sheets%201.0.pdf